# reading header in python from csv

Tags: python, parsing, csv

Is there a way to inject the header array into the header vector in a more efficient way without using any packages such as csv, pandas, etc...?

```
data = []
b = 1
with open(datafile, "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        if b:
            header=line.strip('\n').split(',')
            b = 0
            continue
        entries=line.strip('\n').split(',')
        data.append(dict(zip(header,entries)))
        #print data
return data
```

Comment: That looks like csv.DictReader minus a lot of edge-case handling.

Comment: I can imagine situations where you might not want or might not be able to use `pandas`; but what's the reason to avoid `csv`?

Comment: No reason. I wanted to write it like this for educational purposes.

Comment: If you're going to write one for educational purposes, you should make it non-trivial.  Handling quoting correctly would be a good feature to add.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to go through the same file twice, yielding values is usually better than returning a list.

```
with open(datafile, "rb") as f:
    header = next(f).strip('\n').split(',')
    for line in f:
        entry=line.strip('\n').split(',')
        yield dict(zip(header,entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrite your code using list comprehension. I don't know it is fast or slow. And I think it is not easy to read. Use it just educational purposes.

```
datafile = "hoge.csv"
l = [line.strip('\n').split(',') for line in open(datafile, "rb")]
data = [dict(zip(l[0],r)) for r in l[1:]]
```